# Capture images and store into specific path

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

In the below code I am trying to capture images and store it into the path that I have specified the code runs fine without any errors but the images are not stored. This is my code
The name I am trying to give is the same as the folder name that already exists

```
import cv2
import os

name = input("Enter your name ")
path = "/home/rahul/Downloads/opencv-face-recognition/"+name

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

count = 0
while True:
    ret,test_img=cap.read()
    if not ret :
        continue
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, "frame%d.jpg" % count), test_img)     
    count += 1
    resized_img = 
    cv2.resize(test_img, (640, 480))
    cv2.imshow('Face Register ',resized_img)
    if cv2.waitKey(100) == ord('q'):
        break
    elif count > 60:
        break 


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please, use the code block to properly format your code snippet... your output path could be malformed, check it is a valid path.

Comment: hi thank you for your response. i have checked the path it is correct and also i given read write and execute permission too.